# Facing null pointer exception while merging documents using iText 5.5.3

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm passing 2 documents in the form of streams and trying to merge them into a single pdf. In the first iteration of the loop everything works fine, but miraculously during the second iteration it throws a null pointer exception. Both the streams passed are actually the same, being used as two separate streams.

Code :

```
public synchronized void doMerge(InputStream[] streams,OutputStream out) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("Starting To Merge Files...");
    System.out.println("Total Number Of Files To Be Merged..." +
                      streams.length + "\n");
    try {

        int fileIndex = 0;
        Document document = null;
        PdfCopy writer = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;

        for (fileIndex = 0; fileIndex < streams.length; fileIndex++) {


            System.out.println("Loop No : "+ (fileIndex+1));

            reader = new PdfReader(streams[fileIndex]);
            System.out.println("Reader "+ (fileIndex+1) +" created successfully");

            if (fileIndex == 0) {

            document = new Document();
            System.out.println("Document created successfully");

            writer = new PdfSmartCopy(document, out);
            System.out.println("Reader created successfully");

            document.open();

            }

            writer.addDocument(reader);
            System.out.println("Document "+ (fileIndex+1)+" merged" );
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("Reader "+ (fileIndex+1)+" closed" );
        }



        document.close();
        System.out.println("Document successfully closed");

        System.out.println("File has been merged and written to-" + out);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(in exception block");
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}
```

This is the output i get when i send 2 streams in the input :

```
Loop No : 1
Reader 1 created successfully
Document created successfully
Reader created successfully
Document 1 merged
Reader 1 closed
Loop No : 2
in exception block
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Where (in which line) does the exception occur exactly and what is the complete stack trace?

Comment: I assume that the exception is being thrown when the reader is trying to read the pdf at index 1 (i.e 2nd stream), as the code is printing the value "Loop : 2". Here is the stack trace i see :

com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.

Comment: What happens when you upgrade to iText 5.5.6? I know that we had a problem with `NullPointerExceptions` wen merging forms and documents with a structure tree. This was fixed. Also: aren't you closing your `reader` too early? And how come you create a new `Document` inside the loop over the different documents? Your code looks awkward. Where did you find it?

Comment: Bruno - if you can help me with a better code it would be really great. To my utter surprise this code works absolutely fine when we send 3 or more streams.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie Will the same code behave differently when i use 5.5.6? I have modified the basic merge pdf code from itext_so-sample.pdf, by creating a document only once, when it encounters the first stream. This has to move to production, so your inputs would be of great help.

Comment: *Both the streams passed are actually the same, being used as two separate streams.* - Do you mean the same instance? E.g. for some `InputStream is` and some `OutputStream os` you do `doMerge(new InputStream[]{is,is}, os)`? That would explain your issue: In the first iteration the contents of `is` are read and in the second there is no content anymore to read.

Comment: mkl - that is not the case what you are thinking. Its like i have copied the same pdf on two different location, but the files (in content) are actually the same. The method works perfectly fine when i used the stream placed at 3+ locations (with the same body).